# What's the simplest way to use authentication in ASP.NET with Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, razor-2

I'm new to ASP.NET/Entity Framework, and am trying to get simple signup/login working with EF. Basically, I want to create a new user with custom columns in a table that's accessible from my Entity Framework database context. Something along the lines of:

```
Auth.CreateUser(Username, Password, new { "Email" = Email, "Realname" = Realname, "JoinDate" = JoinDate });
DbContext db = new DbContext();
var User = db.Users.Where(a => a.Email = "some@email.com").FirstOrDefault();
string Realname = User.Realname;
```

Should I use SimpleMembership or what with it? And how would I make it accessible from EF? I really want to use one of the built-in membership providers, since the last one I did was a custom one (in PHP) and it got kind of messy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the easy way you can use SimpleMembership Provider or
You can use your own custom membership provider that Inherit from

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider
```

If you are using SimpleMembership you can get access User data by executing :

```
db.Users.Find(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

UserId in Membership is related to key in Users table, so you can get user data by filtering the key.